# Decode X-UI-Filterresults: Mail header

Tags: php, email, base64, imap, decode

I try to fetch e-mails via IMAP.
Using Zend/PHP it is easy to read usual e-mails. I have issues with specific e-mails that contain a X-UI-Filterresults header. The content has encoding, but I cannot find out which one. It is similar to base64. Thunderbird e-mail client can intepret this code. My goal is to get plain text from code below.

Here is an example:

```
X-UI-Filterresults: notjunk:1;V01:K0:5nqwbO0h:ksRJnCGrxyWVJoIxDjfeWnR1O5N0qSbAV4b 2yH+afmm73MMo0y5H+h906btns1S0X18YiQWQakc/htNW63Z4wc3X9ur/0KtnD64j1x22 GI fnWrrFyl73TzLGlm+BDOHCQDzUfQblrrvzqLIItoDPAkM7eM7MfilxaY/djS8RUmGfnjH v8 R7fN8SP72oE16G+u1cNuA1Ur+Z+Lpo4yaLyeloucJ5E/KlU9vLSxU3wN3xP7RCceXK8oQ yL AfpI9+A+k3JVm7MmlGpVD7yDOaGMgZ1kIbIeAN0fd/HobBUrn5RyOqIvU6XcWdJ25pKMI fg UY9Neko0djFBhBGrBPTJFYY4bn/1q0lFNmx40Aw/iNUfPUrdnGIbz7kIwLOu0b41jQV8P VN +osBaGxPCbgzhP8kMa9sq42GbLfPqZv0RrvZFoU2t3NdYw4RTon75D+J7AzcA7yzTvhsT TX KWubmZ50eqMQudo5hqH4CNGxg5IGeQEk+5d3h7ANAxTP7F0CqhcR7w8gPkq7xydAajntF aL 06y8lWcxSFG+zdhhcLGfd9GViAINxTiWx9nJp01beIJ99TNdMfzf9QSTt9JqNdR4sqyM/ H/ cDGEPKjTlqKUYgS+y7JimCks+aVeqgS0SNZPUFKOFa7GsGgNd7ZxTflO5VtgRxXk3awJq uk d72ZjZVi8aNEo6HQpSIufTar1DtiGjfbtWIVlFZcl0U28UmuVhsYS6Jac1hMql+3o3RF1 C/ ZuDnHwh1c9pu1HzFHWE89m+rK4eWf/XcSS0Iqin6HjiNFMVYnvQYL/SxBTDeASTjlYqCl lj I6rrU0hujreb3DY5IYdTMTOUOX+5mlSkSoL/hRiniyK8IB3HPCj7QS7mnhGAREjG6eu3n Xf w/WleEaouC/eVoqm0Hlxhm4jATmgiu1WBf7gAvc5NXRHoht8zSV9JpBV23mKHG9oAq650 Ll TvPPd3W9msQSDXAeS4iMQccAxXX6MPKgHXZgDfobUGagjasynJBiHjkLxIRkayXa8+iCM 8J p92LB/HPwTfTy7CtWw4iLntJ5OBp56tT4sU+rFhAbUFFhYalwRzxpsjoqkrNpC86QSJAJ Gi E5MwpS6EMeepzDghjqVMTqwXAxN2xsQVty+MJPwcfS1d3kDtqqJA0EU1BEYw9b1rqfKxQ bZ KAbbLQB2BTSTLPd1DOMuQLsx48dPcYzjhv0sAgrUQqmH+Krws5AoYJ8nq0GBwv3xDJA==
```

I hope you could provide help.
Reagards

Comment: Who is inserting this header?  It is obviously a custom header.  It looks to be a few fields separated by colons, and the last field is base64 with +/ as the extra 2 characters.  Once decoded, I don't recognize the data, it just appears to be binary.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes it seems to have 2-3 fields. I tried to decode the large one with base64 and got the same result as you did, just some binary. However I found out this message pattern is often related to spam, but there's nothing documented. Thunderbird could decode this with easy, but I don't know how.

Comment: Thats exactly my question! How did you manage to make Thunderbird decode this "code" ?

Comment: btw: your x-ui-result-example seems to be malformed, because it contains spaces (my examples do not).

Comment: Thunderbird can't decode this header, you mistook the mail body as decoded content. United Internet seems to encrypt or at least obfuscate the details of their spam filter rules.

Comment: "I have issues" is a very bad description of a problem. What exactly are the issues, and why do you depend on this header?

Answer (score 3):

The "X-UI-Filterresults" header is inserted by "UI" which is "United Internet".
GMX, 1&1, web.de and some other belong to UI.